# Returning same class object to UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have used the UIPageViewController for loading around 5 images in a webview.
So whenever the below line of code

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *) pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

, is called, the return object is a class object(in my case class name is LoadPage). Everything works fine in my code, but I am facing some weird problem here and little uncomfortable.

So I planned to move to single class instead of two.

Now the return type for this method will be self.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return self;

}
```

Am I right?

But When I try to initialize the UIPageViewController, the application is getting crashed at one particular line.

```
- (void) createViewControllers {

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options: nil];

    pageViewController.delegate = self; 
    pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    NSArray*    nextScreens = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self];
    [pageViewController setViewControllers: nextScreens direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [[self view] addSubview:[pageViewController view]];     //CRASH
    [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect,0, 0);
    pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;    

    self.view.gestureRecognizers = pageViewController.gestureRecognizers; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return self in `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController` because that would produce a cycle in the view controller hierarchy.

You add the pageViewController as child view controller to self and then later the pageViewController adds self as child view controller (page) to itself. Thats not allowed!

Comment: So you mean, If I use the UIPageViewController, it is mandatory that I need to use another class i.e ViewController ?

Comment: yes of course. it's silly to add the root view controller as a child to it's child.

Comment: it is a good practise to make the pageViewController the window.rootViewController and implement the delegate in the app delegate.

Comment: Sorry that I didnt noticed that child view controller

Comment: Oh. You mean in App delegate ? . I guess I can't do that . because the application which I am developing, will have the pageviewcontroller only after 4 viewcontrollers

Comment: @phix23 thats not great practise as it only works if your pageViewController is going to be the root view controller. Using UIViewController containment is better.